# Alphabetically sorting URLs to Download Image

Tags: python, sorting

Having an issue with the sorting of urls. The .jpg files end in "xxxx-xxxx.jpg". The second set of keys need to be sorted in alphabetical order. Thus far I've only been able to sort the first set of characters alphabetically (which is not necessary).

For instance:

http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/p-babf-bbac.jpg

is proceeding

http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/p-babh-bajc.jpg

when

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

# Google's Python Class
# http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/

import os
import re
import sys
import requests

"""Logpuzzle exercise
Given an apache logfile, find the puzzle urls and download the images.

Here's what a puzzle url looks like:
10.254.254.28 - - [06/Aug/2007:00:13:48 -0700] "GET /~foo/puzzle-bar-aaab.jpg HTTP/1.0" 302 528 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
"""

def url_sort_key(url):
    print url [-8:]
#Extract the puzzle urls from inside a logfile
def read_urls(filename):
    """Returns a list of the puzzle urls from the given log file,
    extracting the hostname from the filename itself.
    Screens out duplicate urls and returns the urls sorted into
    increasing order."""
    # +++your code here+++



# Use open function to search fort the urls containing "puzzle/p"
# Use a line split to pick out the 6th section of the filename
# Sort out all repeated urls, and return sorted list
    with open(filename) as f:
        out = set()
        for line in f:
            if re.search("puzzle/p", line):
                url = "http://code.google.com" + line.split(" ")[6]
                print line.split(" ")
                out.add(url)
    return sorted(list(out))



# Complete the download_images function, which takes a sorted
# list of urls and a directory
def download_images(img_urls, dest_dir):
    """Given the urls already in the correct order, downloads
    each image into the given directory.
    Gives the images local filenames img0, img1, and so on.
    Creates an index.html in the directory
    with an img tag to show each local image file.
    Creates the directory if necessary.
    """
    # ++your code here++
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)

    # Create an index
    index = file(os.path.join(dest_dir, 'index.html'), 'w')
    index.write('<html><body>\n')

    i = 0
    for img_url in img_urls:
        i += 1
        local_name = 'img%d' %i
        print "Retrieving...", local_name
        print local_name 
        print dest_dir
        print img_url

        response = requests.get(img_url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            f = open(os.path.join(dest_dir,local_name + ".jpg"), 'wb')
            f.write(response.content)
            f.close()

        index.write ('<img src="%s">' % (local_name + ".jpg"))


    index.write('\n</body></html>\n')
    index.close()

def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]

    print args
    if not args:
        print ('usage: [--todir dir] logfile ')
        sys.exit(1)

    todir = None
    if args[0] == '--todir':
        todir = args[1]
        del args[0:2]


    img_urls = read_urls(args[0])

    if todir:
        download_images(img_urls, todir)
    else:
        print ('\n'.join(img_urls))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think the error lies in the return for the read_urls function, but am not positive.

Comment: can you add a sample output showing what you want vs what you're getting?

Comment: can you please describe the problem a bit better? You mention two sets... where are they? What are they?

Comment: do you mean in "xxxx-yyyy.jpg" the x's and the y's form the two "sets" with which you want to sort? (I'd call them keys). I assume the two keys must have be sorted in a different order or the second one (y's) must be sorted first, otherwise a simple ordering would do

Comment: it's still far from clear. Please provide an EXAMPLE. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Pynchia I misunderstood the goal, I was operating under the assumption that both set of keys in each URL need to be alphabetized, but am now realizing this is not possible. So my next thought was, it must be the second set of keys that need to be alphabetized for this to work.

Comment: alright, see if my updated answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the urls end in the format 
`xxxx-yyyy.jpg`

and you want to sort the urls based on the second key, i.e. `yyyy`

```
def read_urls(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        s = {el.rstrip() for el in f if 'puzzle' in el}
    return sorted(s, key=lambda u: u[-8:-4]) # u[-13:-9] if need to sort on the first key
```

For example, with an input file containing

```
http://localhost/p-xxxx-yyyy.jpg
http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/p-babf-bbac.jpg
http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/p-babh-bajc.jpg
http://localhost/p-xxxx-yyyy.jpg
```

it produces the list

```
['http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/p-babh-bajc.jpg',
 'http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/images/puzzle/p-babf-bbac.jpg']
```

i.e. `bajc` comes before `bbac`.

See the comment in the code, in case you want to sort by the first key (`xxxx`)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you for the assistance.